# R: Select multiple values from vector of sequences

Tags: r, vector, sequence, indices

In R I'm trying to figure out how to select multiple values from a predefined vector of sequences (e.g. `indices = c(1:3, 4:6, 10:12, ...)`). In other words, if I want a new vector with the 3rd, 5th, and 7th entries in "indices", what syntax should I use to get back a vector with just those sequences intact, e.g. `c(10:12, ...)`?

Comment: `indices[c(3, 5, 7)]`

Comment: You're probably getting down voted because this is a very basic R subsetting question.  Almost any intro to R text/blog/tutorial would cover this...

Comment: I've already tried indices[c(3,5,7)] and I am not getting back a vector of sequences. Instead I'm getting back c(3,5,7).

Comment: In other words, I want to syntax that gives me back the 3rd, 5th and 7th sequences as a vector, e.g.  c(10:12, ...).

Comment: You've asked a question, and accepted an answer. Don't further edit the question. Ask a new question as a followup (you can link to this one as a reference).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want the 3rd, 5th, and 7th entry in `c(1:3, 4:6, 10:12, ...)`, which means you want extract specific *sets* of indices from a vector.

When you do something like `c(1:3, 4:6, ...)`, the resulting vector isn't what it sounds like you want. Instead, use `list(1:3, 4:6, ...)`. Then you can do this:

```
indices <- list(1:3, 4:6, 10:12, 14:16, 18:20)

x <- rnorm(100)

x[c(indices[[3]], indices[[5]])]
```

This is equivalent to:

```
x[c(10:12, 18:20)]
```

That is in turn equivalent to:

```
x[c(10, 11, 12, 18, 19, 20)]
```

Please let me know if I've misinterpreted your question.

Comment: Your first answer should work if I turn it into a loop, because the sequences I want are changing with each sample that I'm extracting.

Comment: @ksed: Excellent. Glad you found a way to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is how to subset data.  Most commonly it is done using square bracket notation:

sample data:

```
my_vector <- c(100:120)
my_vector
# 100 101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108 109 110 111 112 113 114 115 116 117 118 119 120
```

values you want taken out:

```
indices <- c(1:3, 4:6, 10:12)
indices

# 1  2  3  4  5  6 10 11 12
```

subsetting using bracket notation

```
my_vector[indices]
# 100 101 102 103 104 105 109 110 111
```

there is also a function called `subset` can can do this as well.

Comment: You misunderstood what I wanted. See Alex's post for essentially what I needed. I have updated the original question to make what I want more clear. But the standard R, which you are quoting, do not answer what I wanted to know.

Comment: Ahh.. My apologies.  Glad to know you got the answer you were looking for